# Upload Image To 3rd Party (imgur-esque) PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload

I want to use PHP to upload a user-supplied picture to a website like imgur, but not imgur because it wants me to use some weird postman thing that I can't uninstall now. I don't know how to do it, and have spent an hour searching. I know stackoverflow uses imgur, but I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

in your php.ini set 
file_uploads = On

```
 <?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The php.ini file should be in the root PHP directory. If you are using shared hosting you don't have access to that file. Some times on shared hosting you can create a PHP.ini file and place it in the root of your web site and it will work. If you don't have access at all to that file your best bet is to use BOX API or similar to store the image on the cloud and access it that way. You would have to sign up for a BOX developer account.

Comment: I have a php-production.ini, is it the same?